# Main gallery images not centering

Tags: html, css, image, center

The main image at the top does not seem to centre in internet explorer. Any help greatly appreciated:

Webpage URL: http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?

Code:

```
<div class="fadein">
Images</div>


</div><!-- End Images -->
</div><!-- End Main -->
</div><!-- End Photo -->
```

Comment: Wow. You're an ebay developer? Which IE?

Comment: Mainly Internet explorer 8 if poss! Any help greatly appreciated. Cheers..

Comment: I'm not really seeing the problem... Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Basically everything is centered nicely and the image just pops left flush with "photo" div when should be in middle. IE8 definitely not working here. Thanks Max.!

Answer (score 0):

Just add update in your code, hope this will help :

```
#home .photo {
    background: url("http://www.example.com/path/to/image.gif");
}
```